# How to create top level error handling in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Sometimes the bot are having some unexpected error, while the bot are already on live and I don't have the log every moment. Which makes me don't know where the error is occurring from. Therefore, I want to make a top level error handling, so that in every time the bot has error on something, it won't crash and it can be logging the error to a channel.

To make the code more clean, and without repeating all the same stuff, I want to keep the error handling part at the command handler level since I want to create a universal format of error handling, without editing the lower level file (commands being executed by the handler).

Below is my code, the `await commandFile.run` part is the code that the handler execute the command file. I have tried using `catch` method but it just doesn't work when there are errors when executing the command.

```js
    client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {

        if (interaction.isChatInputCommand()) {
            let args = [];

            for (i = 0; i < interaction.options._hoistedOptions.length; i++) {
                args.push({
                    name: interaction.options._hoistedOptions[i].name,
                    value: interaction.options._hoistedOptions[i].value
                })
            }

            let commandFile = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
            if (commandFile) await commandFile.run(client, interaction, args, DefaultFooter, LocalMap)
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log('Execution Error: ' + err)
                })
            console.log(`${interaction.member ? interaction.member.user.tag : interaction.user.tag} executed command (Slash): ${interaction}`);
        }

        if (interaction.isContextMenuCommand()) {
            let commandFile = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
            if (commandFile) await commandFile.run(client, interaction, DefaultFooter, LocalMap);
            console.log(`${interaction.member ? interaction.member.user.tag : interaction.user.tag} executed command (Context): ${interaction.commandName}`);
        }

    })
```

For demonstration, below I also have included the command file that I have used for making error on purposely:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    run: async (client, interaction, args, DefaultFooter, LocalMap) => {
        interaction.reply({ content: 'test' });
        interaction.reply({ content: 'test' });
        return;
    },
    config: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('test')
        .setDescription('testing')
        .setDefaultPermission(false)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using an event listener for the `unhandledRejection` event in your code?

When an asynchronous operation encounters errors but don't have an specific way to handle them, an unhandled rejection is generated. This can lead to your application crashing without showing you errors, which is something we don't like. One common practice is to place this event listener in the main file of your bot instead of the handler so that it covers all the code.

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (error) => {
     console.error('Unhandled Error', error);
     // ... your custom to channel logger
});
```